# page theme causing "Failed to load viewstate." error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-3.5

In my web.config I have the following:

```
<pages theme="myTheme" enableSessionState="true" validateRequest="false" 
enableEventValidation="false" viewStateEncryptionMode="Never" 
enableViewStateMac="false">
```

As soon as I added the theme property I instantly started to receive:

> Failed to load viewstate.  The control
>   tree into which viewstate is being 
>   loaded must match the control tree
>   that was used to save viewstate 
>   during the previous request.For
>   example, when adding controls
>   dynamically,  the controls added
>   during a post-back must  match the
>   type and position of the controls
>   added during the initial request.

When I remove the theme, I no longer get viewstate errors.  Can anyone offer inside to what is happening or how to fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by:

1. Adding `runat="server"` and `ID` attributes to link (stylesheet)
2. Calling `Page.Header.FindControl("link").DataBind()` in Page_Load method of master page.

Do not call `Page.Header.DataBind();` since it will databind the entire header.